# ImportError at /admin/ No module named 'honeywordHasher.hashers.honeywordgen'; 'honeywordHasher.hashers' is not a package

Tags: python, django, passwords, salt, password-hash

I am trying to make my own customize password hasher and i still cannot manage to import it because of this error . How to fix this error?

**Complete traceback:**

```
During handling of the above exception (module 'honeywordHasher.hashers' has no attribute '__path__'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  315.                     match = condition.eval(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in eval
  892.         return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  708.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  849.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  911.                             current = current()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in has_usable_password
  125.         return is_password_usable(self.password)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in is_password_usable
  30.         identify_hasher(encoded)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in identify_hasher
  154.     return get_hasher(algorithm)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in get_hasher
  127.         hashers = get_hashers_by_algorithm()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in get_hashers_by_algorithm
  102.     return {hasher.algorithm: hasher for hasher in get_hashers()}

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in get_hashers
  91.         hasher_cls = import_string(hasher_path)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py" in import_string
  20.     module = import_module(module_path)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/
Exception Value: No module named 'honeywordHasher.hashers.honeywordgen'; 'honeywordHasher.hashers' is not a package
```

The password hasher app name is honeywordHasher.

This is my settings.py:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'honeywordHasher.hashers.honeywordgen.honeywordgen',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

I follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading-without-requiring-a-login) as guidelines, and I am stuck at settings.py.I still cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: did you add `honeywordHasher` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: To be considered an importable module (in Python 2), the directory must contain an `__init__.py` file.  Do the `honeywordHasher` directories contain these files?

Comment: yes it have __init__.py file @JohnGordon

Comment: yes i did add honeywordHasher to my INSTALLED_APPS @BearBrown

Comment: and you have `__init__.py` inside the `honeywordHasher\hashers` directory?

Comment: yes i have it @BearBrown